# How to update row element of SQL database where its value is dependent on another elemnt of the same row by a python function?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Is there any way to use a python function in the SQL statement?

I have a python function returning a value basaed on the input:

```
newvalue = myfunc(input_value)
```

I have the SQL table "users" with columns:

```
id, name, some_value_of_user, value_to_be_calculated
```

I would like to update (all) rows by using the function myfunc without extracting in each row some_value_of_user then using myfunc(some_value_of_user) and then separately updateing the value_to_be_calculated of the row.

I would expect something like this:

```
mycursor.execute(
    "UPDATE users SET value_to_be_calculated = %s WHERE value_to_be_calculated = NULL", 
    myfunc(some_value_of_user)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't. Either rewrite that function as a stored procedure in MySQL, or fetch and update the rows one by one.

Comment: The only way would be to write the function into the SQL.  For instance if your function is 4 X [some_value_of_user] and 4 would be the result of your function based on the data typed into your form this time it would become SET [value_to_be_calculated] = %s * [some_value_of_user].  If your function is dependent on the value in the row you would need to fetch and update each row.